# Extracting read counts matched to each gene symbol

Tags: r, loops, rna-seq

I have quantified gene expression by Salmon that gives me Ensembl transcripts, I converted Ensembl transcripts to gene symbol but for some genes I multiple transcripts; How I could collapse read counts to genes, I tried `tximport` package but I found that too hard as my annotation is different.

```
Name                NumReads
ENST00000355520.5   407.186
ENST00000566753.1   268.879
ENST00000481617.2   242.25
ENST00000538183.2   226.576

ensembltranscript_id gene_name
ENST00000482226.2   FCGR2C
ENST00000508651.1   FCGR2C
ENST00000571914.1   TSPAN10
ENST00000571707.1   TSPAN10
ENST00000534817.1   OVCH2
ENST00000445557.1   OR52E1
ENST00000575319.1   CYP2D7
ENST00000576465.1   CYP2D7
```

> EDITED

This is output of Salmon read counts

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bkril0v6sw7v9z/Salmon_output.txt?dl=0

And this is when I converted transcript ids in Salmon output to gene name

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m1iybfbu2i4bb39/Converting_transcript_id_to_gene_id.txt?dl=0

Comment: Could you add what you expect as your output and what code has already failed?

Comment: A possible strategy is to group gene expression by gene symbols and then to average expression values across different Ensembl transcript IDs for the same gene symbol. If you were to provide representative sample data (your current sample data does not contain any expression values from different Ensembl IDs with identical gene symbol) it will be a lot easier for others to help.

Comment: Please, do not use links (btw: the links don't work). Instead create your base data and your expected output in your request/question. Just a couple of lines will be fine. So that people who are willing to help get an exact idea of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package dplyr.

Create test table:

```
names = c("ensembltranscript_id",  "gene_name", "NumReads")
transcripts = c("ENST00000482226.2", "ENST00000508651.1", "ENST00000571914.1", "ENST00000571707.1", "ENST00000534817.1")
gene_names = c("FCGR2C", "FCGR2C", "TSPAN10", "TSPAN10", "OVCH2")
reads = c(205.56, 456.21, 123.3, 52.6, 268.45)

data = data.frame(transcripts, gene_names, reads)
names(data) = names
```

Do the calculation:

```
result = data %>% 
  group_by(gene_name) %>% 
  summarise(sum(NumReads)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, format, 2)
```

Print the result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  gene_name `sum(NumReads)`
  <fct>     <chr>          
1 FCGR2C    661.77         
2 OVCH2     268.45         
3 TSPAN10   175.90
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

As stated in the comments of the OP, an expected output would help.
Sorry, maybe I misunderstood 'collapse' in this context. My interpretation is in adding up the reads per gene-name.

**Edit2:**

As mentioned in my comment, try to prevent to provide links. Links can be broken etc. For full instructions on how to write a good post see: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

However, based on your real data do the following:

Load the data:

```
salmon_reads = read.table(file = "/path/to/Salmon_output.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
genes = read.table(file = "/path/to/Converting_transcript_id_to_gene_id.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
```

Simply merge the data by there transcript-id:

```
merged_data = merge(x = salmon_reads, y = genes, by.x = colnames(salmon_reads)[1], by.y = colnames(genes)[1], all = T)
```

Do the calculation and order for decreasing reads:

```
result = merged_data %>% 
  group_by(external_gene_name) %>% 
  summarise(sum(NumReads)) %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, format, 2)

result$`sum(NumReads)` = as.numeric(result$`sum(NumReads)`)
result = result[order(result$`sum(NumReads)`, decreasing = T),]
```

You did not mention how to handle NAs. In this scenario all reads for gene-names which are NA are summed up. This is why NA has the most reads.

Comment: Thank you for being this much helpful